# Haskell split user input

Tags: haskell

I want to take first three elements from user input in Haskell, but I got error message.
Thank you for the help

```
 getCmd cmd = do
    putStrLn take 3 cmd 

 main = do 
    putStrLn "please type something"
    name <- getLine
    if name /= "QUIT" then do 
        getCmd(name)
        main
    else
        return()
```

Comment: You should always post your error message. Regardless, you're typing like you're in Java or C.
For instance, replace `getCmd(name)` with `getCmd name`...

Comment: You need to change the body of `getCmd` to be `putStrLn $ take 3 cmd`

Comment: @Lee Hi lee I am new for haskell. Could you tell me what is the "$"  mean? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of `getCmd` should be:

```
getCmd cmd = do
    putStrLn (take 3 cmd)
```

function application is left-associative so your definition is parsed as

```
(((putStrLn take) 3) cmd)
```

so you need to add the brackets so `putStrLn` is applied to the result of applying `take`.

Haskell also defines the `$` infix operator which has a lower precedence than function application so it is commonly used instead of using brackets. Your use of `do` is also redundant so you can define `getCmd` as

```
getCmd cmd = putStrLn $ take 3 cmd
```

or even

```
getCmd = putStrLn . take 3
```

Comment: Another enhancement is to use `when` from `Control.Monad` as it's exactly an `if` with `return ()` in `else` branch.